# Attribute Styles in Affinity Designer?

Tags: style, affinity-designer

In Affinity Designer, is it possible to set up attribute styles which can be applied to individual layers or objects? Say I have a palette of three colors that I will use in my design project, and I want to set up three fill styles, named FillColor1, FillColor2  and FillColor3. For all of the objects that I  want to fill with the first color, I would apply the style named FillColor1. I would do the same for the other two colors, using FillColor2 and FillColor3 respectively.

Let's say I originally used the color orange for FillColor1, but later decided that I don't like the way it looks. I would like to modify the color setting for the FillColor1 style to green, and it would instantly change all of the orange objects to green.

Is this workflow possible in AD? I don't think the currently implementation of styles will work, and it does not look like symbols will work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, as I found on the Affinity forum, is to use global colors. In case anyone else needs it, the response I got is:

> you can use global colours for this, in the swatches panel>add global
>   colour. or right click on the shape, add to swatches

Here is the link to that forum post post:

[Affinity Forum](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/46597-attribute-styles-in-ad/)

Comment: Could you add what is said behind the link. As data behind links eventually disappear and vendor forums are quite notorious about this kind of stuff.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks for the suggestion; I added the exact response to my answer above. Hope this is what you wanted.